# Select PLANNAME from PACKLIST containing specific COLLID and not containing another specific COLLID?

Tags: sql, database, select, db2

Should be a fairly simple task, I just can't wrap my head around it. I have a table called PACKLIST containing columns like PLANNAME, COLLID etc. I want to  find all the PLANNAME's which contains a specific COLLID 'COL001' and at the same time does not contain COLLID 'COL200'. I have tried alot of different sql, and a simpel WHERE COLLID = 'COL001' AND COLLID != 'COL200' would have been nice if it worked :) Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
with PACKLIST(PLANNAME,COLLID) as
(
 SELECT 'PLAN_1','COL001' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'PLAN_1','COL200' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'PLAN_2','COL200' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'PLAN_3','COL001'
)
SELECT P.PLANNAME,P.COLLID
FROM PACKLIST AS P
WHERE P.COLLID='COL001' AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM PACKLIST AS X
  WHERE X.PLANNAME=P.PLANNAME
  AND X.COLLID='COL200'
)
```

Could you please try the above if it is suitable for you